# User input a list of tuples?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using spyder to code this project if that helps at all.

I am trying to take user input of: (a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)

and store the tuples into a list like: [('a','b'),('b','b'), ... etc

I try to split by commas but then it splits mid-tuple and incorrectly.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: First thing to do: Show your code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is (what I believe) you want. I am only splitting at the commas that are between brackets `i.split('),(')` and then remove the now not needed brackets and split at the remaining commas. (sorry, inline formatting is probably weird).

This is assuming there are no spaces in your input. If there might be you have to strip those. `i = i.replace(' ', '')`

```
i = '(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)' # i = input('Enter a list of tuples: ')

l = []

for tup in i.split('),('):
    #tup looks like `(a,a` or `b,b`
    tup = tup.replace(')','').replace('(','')
    #tup looks like `a,a` or `b,b`
    l.append(tuple(tup.split(',')))

print(l)
```

This returns `[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')]`

Answer (score 1):

You can break it up through steps. I've kept it with strings since that's the example you provided. But you could force it to be integers in the list comprehension if you know that's what the input will be.

```
import re

input = '(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)'
breakdown = re.findall('\(.*?,.*?\)', input)
tup_ls = []
for i in breakdown:
    tup_ls.append(tuple([x for x in i[1:-1].split(',')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = list(tuple(map(int,input().split())) for r in range(int(input('enter no of rows : ')))) 
print(t)
```

input: 3

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
Output => [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

`map` takes less time and takes less memory in some cases than list comprehension. When I calculate time taken by map it is less than time taken by list comprehension so it is time efficient.

Comment: *`map` takes less time and takes less memory in some cases than list comprehension*. Do you have an example?